# Simplifying the predicate when checking for several known values

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin often uses very pragmatic approaches. I wonder whether there is some I don't know of to simplify a filter predicate which just asks for some known values.

E.g. consider the following list:

```
val list = listOf("one", "two", "2", "three")
```

To filter out `"two"` and `"2"` filtering can be accomplished in several ways, e.g.:

```
list.filter {
  it in listOf("two", "2") // but that creates a new list every time... (didn't check though)
}

// extracting the list first, uses more code... and may hide the list somewhere sooner or later
val toCheck = listOf("two", "2")
list.filter { it in toCheck } 

// similar, but probably less readable due to naming ;-)
list.filter(toCheck::contains)

// alternative using when, but that's not easier for this specific case and definitely longer:
list.filter {
    when (it) {
        "two", "2" -> true
        else -> false
    } 
}

// probably one of the simplest... but not so nice, if we need to check more then 2 values
list.filter { it == "two" || it == "2" }
```

I wonder... is there something like `list.filter { it in ("two", "2") }` or any other simple way to create/use a short predicate for known values/constants? In the end that's all I wanted to check.

EDIT: I just realised that the sample doesn't make much sense as `listOf("anything", "some", "other").filter { it in listOf("anything") }` will always be just: `listOf("anything")`. However, the list intersection makes sense in constellations where dealing with, e.g. a `Map`. In places where the filter actually doesn't return only the filtered value (e.g. `.filterKeys`). The subtraction (i.e. `list.filterNot { it in listOf("two", "2") }`) however also makes sense in lists as well.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin provides some set operations on collections which are

- `intersect` (what both collections have in common)
- `union` (combine both collections)
- `subtract` (collections without elements of the other)

In your case, instead of filter, you may use the set operation `subtract`

```
val filteredList  = list.subtract(setOf("two","2"))
```

and there you go.

EDIT:

and the *fun* (pun intended) doesn't end there: you could extend the collections with your own functions such as a missing `outerJoin` or for filtering something like `without` or operators i.e. `/` for `intersect`

For example, by adding these

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.without(other Iterable<T>) = this.subtract(other)
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.excluding(other Iterable<T>) = this.subtract(other)

operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.div(other: Iterable<T>) = this.intersect(other)
```

Your code - when applied to your example using the intersect - would become

```
val filtered = list / filter //instead of intersect filter
```

or - instead of substract:

```
val filtered = list without setOf("two", "2")
```

or

```
val filtered = list excluding setOf("two", "2")
```

Pragmatic enough?

Comment: actually in my case I rather want the intersect, but nonetheless an interesting approach indeed... and as I am lazy, your approach can also be simplified to `list - setOf("two", "2")` ;-) but... time will tell whether this is readable ;-)

Comment: Ok... my sample comment code is rather a `minus` instead of `subtract` ;-) in my actual specific problem I also rather deal with a `Map` and still don't know whether I like it: `(map.keys - setOf("two", "2"))`... I like it when the `filter` is explicitly/better seen... ... hmmm...

Comment: pragmatic.. nearly... somehow... I hoped there was such an extension function already available... but if not I will build something similar I think... I like the last one as it is nicely readable... `list excluding setOf("two", "2")`... but maybe I will go for anything with a vararg... (efficiency is no problem here ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything simpler than to create the filtering list/set and then apply it:

```
val toCheck = listOf("two", "2") 
val filtered = list.filter { it in toCheck }
```

or

```
val toCheck = setOf("two", "2")
val filtered = list.filter { it in toCheck }
```

but if you prefer you can create a `Predicate`:

```
val predicate: (String) -> Boolean = { it in listOf("2", "two") }
val filtered = list.filter { predicate(it) }
```

**Edit**: as for the approach with `minus`, which is not the case here but has been mentioned, it does not provide simplicity or efficiency since itself is using filter:

```
/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection except the elements contained in the given [elements] collection.
 */
public operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.minus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T> {
    val other = elements.convertToSetForSetOperationWith(this)
    if (other.isEmpty())
        return this.toList()
    return this.filterNot { it in other }
}
```

(from **Collections.kt**)

Comment: you can use `list.filter(predicate)` in the last line... but I rather want less code for this specific use case. It's just for places where I want to filter out things, where it is clear what needs to be filtered and where I do not want a separate list for it... but it's only useful in that specific places... You know what I mean?

Comment: As I mentioned, there's nothing simpler than gathering in a list/set all that needs to be the filtering values and if needed reuse it. The predicate is just for elegancy

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following now:

```
fun <E> containedIn(vararg elements: E) = { e:E -> e in elements }
fun <E> notContainedIn(vararg elements: E) = { e:E -> e !in elements }
```

which can be used for maps & lists using `filter`, e.g.:

```
list.filter(containedIn("two", "2"))
list.filter(notContainedIn("two", "2"))
map.filterKeys(containedIn("two", "2"))
map.filterValues(notContainedIn("whatever"))
```

In fact it can be used for anything (if you like):

```
if (containedIn(1, 2, 3)(string.toInt())) {
```

My first approach inspired by Gerald Mückes answer, but with `minus` instead of `subtract` (so it only covers the subtraction-part):

```
(list - setOf("two", "2"))
       .forEach ...
```

Or with own extension functions and using `vararg`:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.without(vararg other: T) = this - other
```

with the following usage:

```
list.without("two", "2")
    .forEach... // or whatever...
```

With the above variant however no infix is possible then. For only one exclusion an infix can be supplied as well... otherwise the `Iterable`-overload must be implemented:

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.without(other : T) = this - other
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.without(other : Iterable<T>) = this - other
```

Usages:

```
list without "two"
list without listOf("two", "2")
```

Comment: Am I missing something? You wanted a filter like `list.filter {  it in listOf("two", "2") 
}`. How can this be the same by using `minus`?!!! You need `intersect`, like `val filtered = list.intersect(listOf("2", "two")).toList()`

Comment: No you didn't. The first part definitely solves both: intersection and subtraction.. the second part is where I just wanted to share my variant of the `without` of Gerald Mücke

Comment: I also updated the question, as a subtraction on a list alone doesn't make any sense...